# Best way to refresh content page without refresh sidebar,navbar, and footer AdminLTE in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

I tried to build admin page with a static sidebar, navbar, and footer, then dynamic content in AdminLTE. It's working with

```js
  $('.nav-link').click(function (event) {
    // Avoid the link click from loading a new page
    event.preventDefault();
    // Load the content from the link's href attribute
    $('.content-wrapper').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

but the problem is, that affects all of nav-link in the entire admin panel, so that's a little buggy when I click something with nav-link class. for example this push-menu

[image: push menu]

If I click that the function is broken and also my sidebar when I want to show the content. Is that any best way to implement a static menu with dynamic content without affecting other related class and can work with Laravel blade feature?